# Apache: как настроить VirtualHost?

Tags: apache, windows-10

Не могу настроить второй хост (*Apache 2.4*).
В файле `httpd-vhosts.conf` прописал:

```
NameVirtualHost *:7777
<Directory L:/temp>
    AllowOverride All
    Options All
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:7777>
    ServerAdmin ya@ya.ru
    DocumentRoot "L:/temp"
    ServerName tempd.ru
    ErrorLog "logs/tempd.ru-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/tempd.ru-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Файл подключен (после рестарта появились лог-файлы). Модуль `mod_log_config` задействован. В хосте прописал, что `tempd.ru` - локальный (`127.0.0.1`). В папке `L:/temp` есть и `index.php`, и `index.html`.
В браузере пишу `http://tempd.ru:7777/` и ничего.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Listen 7777
<VirtualHost *:7777>
    DocumentRoot "L:/temp"
    ServerName tempd.ru
    ErrorLog "logs/tempd.ru-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/tempd.ru-access.log" common
    <Directory L:/temp>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Про листен забыл...